# How to create a 1D Metal Texture?

Tags: swift, metal

I want an array of 1-dimensional data (essentially an array of arrays) that is created at run time, so the size of this array is not known at compile time. I want to easily send the array of that data to a kernel shader using `setTextures` so my kernel can just accept a single argument like `texture1d_array` which will bind each element texture to a different kernel index automatically, regardless of how many there are.

The question is how to actually create a 1D `MTLTexture` ? All the `MTLTextureDescriptor` options seem to focus on 2D or 3D. Is it as simple as creating a 2D texture with the height of 1? Would that then be a 1D texture that the kernel would accept?

I.e.

```
 let textureDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor
        .texture2DDescriptor(pixelFormat: .r16Uint,
                             width: length,
                             height: 1,
                             mipmapped: false)
```

If my data is actually just one dimensional (not actually pixel data), is there is an equally convenient way to use an ordinary buffer instead of `MTLTexture`, with the same flexibility of sending an arbitrarily-sized array of these buffers to the kernel as a single kernel argument?

Answer (score 2):

You can recreate all of those factory methods yourself. I would just use an initializer though unless you run into collisions.

```swift
public extension MTLTextureDescriptor {
  /// A 1D texture descriptor.
  convenience init(
    pixelFormat: MTLPixelFormat = .r16Uint,
    width: Int
  ) {
    self.init()
    textureType = .type1D
    self.pixelFormat = pixelFormat
    self.width = width
  }
}
```

```swift
MTLTextureDescriptor(width: 512)
```

[This is no different than `texture2DDescriptor` with a height of 1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtltexturedescriptor/1516000-height), but it's not as much of a lie. (I.e. yes, a texture can be thought of as infinite-dimensional, with a magnitude of 1 in everything but the few that matter. But we throw out all the dimensions with 1s when saying "how dimensional" something is.)

```swift
var descriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptor(
  pixelFormat: .r16Uint,
  width: 512,
  height: 1,
  mipmapped: false
)
descriptor.textureType = .type1D
descriptor == MTLTextureDescriptor(width: 512) // true
```

——

`textureType = .typeTextureBuffer` takes care of your second question, but why not use `textureBufferDescriptor` then?

Comment: Thanks for the help! Regarding your last point, I can't find any information on what a texture buffer actually is. Is it a texture, or a buffer? This page doesn't even mention it: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/MetalProgrammingGuide/Mem-Obj/Mem-Obj.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43701382/652038